# THREE.WebGLRenderer: Context Lost. React Three Fiber

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I have some kind of issues with `THREE` and `ReactJS` Three Fiber, as I import the canvas in a fresh react project with the dependencies (three, react-three-fiber, use-cannon) installed the canvas shows for millisecond and it shows an error, when I checked the console it showed the following error:

```
THREE.WebGLRenderer: Context Lost.
```

My App.js

```
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import { Canvas } from "react-three-fiber";

function App() {
  return (
    <div style={{ height: "100vh", width: "100vw" }}>
      <Canvas style={{ background: "black" }}></Canvas>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-fiber",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.1.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-three-fiber": "^5.1.5",
    "three": "^0.122.0",
    "use-cannon": "^0.5.3",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please verify if your device can display the [official three.js examples](https://threejs.org/examples/) without producing a context lost? Maybe there is a general issue with your device?

Comment: @Mugen87 yes, it's working totally fine and I even tried plain THREEJS and plain threejs in react. Both are working fine. I'm facing issues when working with the react-three-fiber